# Difference between terrain and plane

Tags: terrain, unity

I'm going to make an environment with trees, walls, rocks, mountains and bushes in Unity 3D 5.1 . I don't know what game object suitable for the ground. I have used both terrain and plane in earlier simple projects.

My question is,

> What is the difference  between terrain and plane?
>
> Which game object is suitable for my requirement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need Terrain as it allows you to add vegetation (Trees & Details), make adjustments to the relief like rise land to form mountains and also it gives you ability to paint textures on it. A plane is a simple game object that can only be scaled on two axes and none of the above can be done with it.

They are both rendered only on one side of the object. By default the terrain object is scaled much larger than a plane.